# React ref undefined

Tags: reactjs, ref

so I'm having a little trouble using ref's with React.

All I'm trying to do is print the text content of an element using ref's like this:

```
export default class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.intro = React.createRef();
    console.log(this.intro.textContent);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.intro}>Hi</div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, this always prints null or undefined instead of "Hi" which is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `current` with `ref`, like `this.ref.current.textContent`

Check the stackblitz demo [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-twpv12)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.intro = React.createRef();
  }

 componentDidMount(){
      console.log( this.intro.current.textContent);
    }

 render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.intro}>Hi</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are logging it in constructor. Run the code in componentDidMount lifecyle.

```
export default class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.intro = React.createRef();

  }


componentDidMount(){
      console.log(this.intro.textContent);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.intro}>Hi</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason, when I do "console.log(this.intro.textContent)" I still get null, even though, when I do "console.log(this.intro)" I get the proper element.

Comment: When i do what? I didnt get you

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it or maybe a link on codepen?

Comment: try this.intro.current.textContent

Answer (score 1):

You are console logging in the constructor before Dom is actually rendered.
Try console logging in an onClick handler instead.

```
export default class SomeClass extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.intro = React.createRef();
 }
 print = () => {
   console.log(this.intro.textContent);
 }
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <div ref={this.intro}>Hi</div>
       <button onClick={this.print}>Print</div>
     </div>
   )
 }
```

}